# How to selectively join based on if column in right table is null or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine you have a `Business` table.

| Id | BusinessName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Goodlife |
| 2 | BadLife |
| 3 | OkayLife |

We also have a `BusinessContact` table containing all contacts for the business.

| Id | BusinessId | Email | ContactType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Manager@Goodlife.com | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | NULL | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | Employee@Goodlife.com | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | Owner@Badlife.com | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | NULL | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | Employee@Badlife.com | 3 |

I want to join `BusinessContact` on `Business`
so example sql:

```
SELECT Business.Id, Email, ContactTypeId FROM Business
JOIN BusinessContact ON Business.Id = BusinessContact.BusinessId
WHERE ContactTypeId IN (1,2) --we only want managers and owners
```

This would give me the following table:

| Id | Email | ContactTypeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Manager@Goodlife.com | 2 |
| 1 | NULL | 1 |
| 2 | Owner@Badlife.com | 1 |
| 2 | NULL | 2 |

What I want to do is only join the contact which has an email address and also always prioritize owner on the join. So if the owner of the business (ContactTypeId = 1) has no email adress, which is the case for BusinessId = 1. Then join the Manager contact.

So the expected result would be:

| Id | Email | ContactTypeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Manager@Goodlife.com | 2 |
| 2 | Owner@Badlife.com | 1 |

Edge cases:

1. If both manager and owner email addresses are null then either the business is included with email and contactypeId columns as null or the business is not in the result table. Whichever outcome does not matter.
2. If both owner and manager have email addresses, we always prioritize owner and that would be the only contact on the resulted table

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected outcome to make your question more clear, thank you

Comment: @GuidoG Done, should be much clearer

Comment: Why don't you use `Email IS NOT NULL` in your query?

Comment: @D-Shih because there might be cases where both owner and manager have email adresses on record, but I only want owner in that scenario since owner is prioritized

Comment: Also, what should happen if both contact emails are null?

Comment: @SOS either it would show the business once with email as null and contactypeid is null. OR the business is not in the result table. Does not matter which

Answer (score 1):

You want the best contact per business. I suggest to use a lateral join on the top contact row for this:

```
SELECT b.id, b.businessname, bc.email, bc.contacttypeid
FROM business b
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP (1) *
  FROM businesscontact bc
  WHERE bc.businessid = b.id
  AND bc.contacttypeid IN (1, 2)
  ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN bc.email IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
    bc.contacttypeid
)
ORDER BY b.id;
```

Use `CROSS APPLY` instead, if you want to dismiss businesses without owner and manager emails. In that case also make the email mandatory:

```
SELECT b.id, b.businessname, bc.email, bc.contacttypeid
FROM business b
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP (1) *
  FROM businesscontact bc
  WHERE bc.businessid = b.id
  AND bc.contacttypeid IN (1, 2)
  AND bc.email IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY bc.contacttypeid
)
ORDER BY b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help

```
select b.id,
       isnull(bc1.email, bc2.email) as email,
       isnull(bc1.contacttypeid, bc2.contacttypeid) as contacttypeid
from   Business b
  outer apply ( select top 1
                       c.email,
                       c.contacttypeid
                from   BusinessContact c
                where  c.businessid = b.id
                and    c.contacttypeid = 1
                and    c.email is not null
              ) bc1
   
  outer apply ( select top 1
                       c.email,
                       c.contacttypeid
                from   BusinessContact c
                where  c.businessid = b.id
                and    c.contacttypeid = 2
              ) bc2
```

Try it out in this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8b3399ea368e9393501c8b0bd5b5b2a)

The result

| id | email | contacttypeid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Manager@Goodlife.com | 2 |
| 2 | Owner@Badlife.com | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

We join to the BusinessContacts twice, once to get the owners and once to get the manager and then use coalesce to get the owners Email if we have it and the managers Email if the owners Email is null.

```
<!-- -->
>     create table Business(
>     id int,
>     bname varchar(20));
>     insert into Business values
>     (1,'Goodlife'),
>     (2,'BadLife');
>     create table BusinessContact(
>     id int,
>     businessId int,
>     Email varchar(30),
>     contactType int);
>     insert into businessContact values
>     (1,   1,  'Manager@Goodlife.com', 2),
>     (2,   1,  NULL,   1),
>     (4,   1,  'Employee@Goodlife.com',    3),
>     (3,   2,  'Owner@Badlife.com',    1),
>     (4,   2,  NULL,   2),
>     (4,   2,  'Employee@Badlife.com', 3);
>     GO
> 
> <pre>
8 rows affected
> </pre>

<!-- -->
>     select bname "Business Name",
>     coalesce( o.email, m.email) "Email Adress"
>     from Business b
>     left join 
>       (select businessid, 
>       email from BusinessContact 
>       where contactType = 1) o on b.id=o.businessid
>     left join 
>       (select businessid, 
>       email from BusinessContact 
>       where contactType = 2) m on b.id=m.businessid
>     GO
> 
> <pre>
> Business Name | Email Adress        
> :------------ | :-------------------
> Goodlife      | Manager@Goodlife.com
> BadLife       | Owner@Badlife.com   
> </pre>

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a53e4481efb5b2190ee474cfaca29989)*
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey this query should work

```
SELECT
b.BusinessName, bc.Email, bc.ContactType
FROM Business b
INNER JOIN BusinessContact bc ON(b.Id = bc.BusinessId)

WHERE bc.ContactType = (
SELECT MIN(bc1.ContactType)
FROM BusinessContact bc1
WHERE bc1.BusinessId = b.Id
AND bc1.Email IS NOT NULL
AND bc1.ContactType BETWEEN 1 AND 2)
ORDER BY b.BusinessName
```

See example here [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=5e92c72399eed331ed097c44792a5a54)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT businessid,email,contacttype FROM 
(
SELECT b.id,
c.*,
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY businessid ORDER BY contacttype) rn 
FROM businesscontact c
INNER JOIN business b
ON b.id = c.businessid
WHERE email IS NOT NULL 
) temp  WHERE temp.rn = 1
ORDER BY businessid;
```